# Refactoring methods to controllers to DI-Container as a service

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, di-containers

hope ur doing well, I'm trying to minimize the repetitive code, so I created methods for each controller, all works fine, now I want to create a new controller for the method and register it in the DI container but unfortunately the Di container doesn't pick it up :This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(System.IServiceProvider, System.Type)

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(object, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder)
```

in services.AddTransient();

this is my method as a controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using QlikviewServer.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;


namespace QlikviewServer.Services
{
    public class GetAZCredidentials //: IUserManager/IHttpContextAccessor<GetAZCredidentials>/<GetAZCredidentials>//GetAZCredidentials//IActionContextAccessor
    {
        private readonly GetAZCredidentials _context;
        DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers;

        public HttpContext HttpContext { get => ((IHttpContextAccessor)_context).HttpContext; set => ((IHttpContextAccessor)_context).HttpContext = value; }

        //     public ActionContext ActionContext { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        private readonly IServiceProvider services;
        public GetAZCredidentials(IServiceProvider services)
        {
            this.services = services;
        }
        public int  GetAZCredidentials1()
        {
           
                //  var person = GetPerson();

                PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
                UserPrincipal user1 = UserPrincipal.Current;

                string displayName2 = user1.DisplayName;

                string displayName = user1.SamAccountName;
                string DistinguishedName = user1.DistinguishedName;
                string[] values = DistinguishedName.Split(',');
                string domain = values[6];
                string[] values2 = domain.Split('=');
                string domain2 = values2[1].Trim();
                string UserPrincipalName2 = user1.UserPrincipalName;
                var comp = values[4];
                var company_id = comp.Split('=');
                var company_id2 = company_id[1].Trim();
                List<ApplicationUser> groupsad = (from m in _context.ApplicationUsers
                                                  select new ApplicationUser { ApplicationUserId = m.ApplicationUserId, UserName = m.UserName, NameAdmin = m.NameAdmin, DisplayName = m.DisplayName, UserPrincipalName = m.UserPrincipalName }).ToList();




                var groups2 = (from m in _context.ApplicationUsers
                               select m).ToList();

                for (int i = 0; i < groupsad.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupsad[i].NameAdmin.Trim()))
                    {
                        groupsad[i].NameAdmin = groupsad[i].NameAdmin.Trim();
                    }
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupsad[i].UserName.Trim()))

                    {
                        groupsad[i].UserName = groupsad[i].UserName.Trim();
                    }


                    _context.ApplicationUsers.Where(it => it.NameAdmin == groupsad[i].NameAdmin).ToList()
                      .ForEach(
                           it =>
                           {

                               var it2 = it.NameAdmin.TrimEnd();

                               if (it2 == displayName)
                               {
                                   it.DisplayName = displayName2;
                               }

                           }


                            );



                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupsad[i].UserPrincipalName.Trim()))
                    {

                        _context.ApplicationUsers.Where(it => it.NameAdmin == groupsad[i].NameAdmin).ToList()
                       .ForEach(
                            it =>
                            {

                                var it2 = it.NameAdmin.TrimEnd();

                                if (it2 == displayName)
                                {
                                    it.UserPrincipalName = UserPrincipalName2;
                                }
                            }
                                );

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        groupsad[i].UserPrincipalName = groupsad[i].UserPrincipalName.Trim();

                    }




                    var usersadmitted = (from m in _context.ApplicationUsers
                                         select new ApplicationUser { NameAdmin = m.NameAdmin, UserName = m.UserName }).ToList();
                 //   ViewBag.ad = (from m in _context.ApplicationUsers
               //                   select new ApplicationUser { NameAdmin = m.NameAdmin }).ToList();

                }
                foreach (ApplicationUser f in groupsad)
                {
                    if (f.NameAdmin.Trim() == displayName)
                    {

                        if (f.UserName.Trim() == "reader" || f.UserName.Trim() == "admin" && domain2 == "Vionet")
                        {
                //            if (f.UserName.Trim() == "reader") { ViewBag.reader_admin = "reader"; }
                //            if (f.UserName.Trim() == "admin") { ViewBag.reader_admin = "admin"; }


                            return 1;


                        }
                    }
                    return 2;
                }
                return 3;
            }

       
    }

    public interface IUserManager
    {
    }

    public interface IHttpContextAccessor<T>
    {
    }

    public interface IActionContextAccessor<T>
    {
    }
}
```

and finally I call it if it would work as

```
var result1 = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<GetAZCredidentials>();
          
            if (result1 != 1)
            {
```

thus depending on the return type 1,2,or 3 take appropriate action, any input will be highly appreciated as this my first refactoring, thank you in advance

Comment: What's the exception you are getting?

Comment: InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection' has been registered.